# If/Else statement is not when trying to grab address list

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to run an if/else statement on the following URL:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=MK3+5JE&viewbox=-147.13%2C72.78%2C147.13%2C-55.67

and

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=MK1+1AS&viewbox=-147.13%2C72.78%2C147.13%2C-55.67

My code is below:

```
; Collect results 1
Sleep 1000
Addr1 := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML
If Substr(Addr1, 1, 2) = "MK"
    {
    StringSplit, AddrNew, Addr1, `,
    StringTrimLeft, AddrNew3, AddrNew3, 1 
    Addr1 := AddrNew2 . "," . AddrNew3 . "," . PostCode
    MsgBox, %Addr1%
    }
Else If Substr(Addr1, 1, 2) <> "MK"
    {
    StringSplit, AddrNew, Addr1, `,
    StringTrimLeft, AddrNew2, AddrNew2, 1 
    Addr1 := AddrNew1 . "," . AddrNew2 . "," . PostCode
    MsgBox, %Addr1%
    }

; Collect results 2
Sleep 1000
Addr := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[2].innerHTML
If Substr(Addr, 1, 2) = "MK"
    {
    StringSplit, AddrNew, Addr2, `,
    StringTrimLeft, AddrNew3, AddrNew3, 1 
    Addr := AddrNew2 . "," . AddrNew3 . "," . PostCode
    MsgBox, %Addr%
    }
Else If Substr(Addr, 1, 2) <> "MK"
    {
    StringSplit, AddrNew, Addr2, `,
    StringTrimLeft, AddrNew2, AddrNew2, 1 
    Addr := AddrNew1 . "," . AddrNew2 . "," . PostCode
    MsgBox, %Addr%
    }
```

Each time I try grabbing the data, the following happens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When the correct output should be

1. Saint Andrew's Road, Far Bletchley
2. Buckingham Road, Far Bletchley
3. Mount Farm, Milton Keynes
4. Dawson Road, Mount Farm

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Did you try to add `end if` at the end of the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I was not keeping track of my variables...

```
    ; Collect results 1
    Sleep 1000
    Addr1 := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innertext
    String_Object := StrSplit(addr1, "`,")
    If (Substr(Addr1, 1, 2) = "MK")
    {
        Addr1 := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr1%
    }
    Else
    {
        Addr1 := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr1%
    }

    ; Collect results 2
    Sleep 1000
    Addr2 := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[1].innertext
    String_Object := StrSplit(addr2, "`,")
    If (Substr(Addr2, 1, 2) = "MK")
    {
        Addr2 := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr2%
    }
    Else
    {
        Addr2 := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr2%
    }
```